# Uninstall Mendeley

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.10, uninstall

How do I completely uninstall Mendeley in order to reinstall it again in Ubuntu 10.10 (64 bit)?

Answer (score 7):

> sudo apt-get remove mendeleydesktop

From http://www.mendeley.com/download-mendeley-desktop/ubuntu/instructions/

Answer (score 2):

If the normal "remove" doesn't work, try with `purge`, it shouldn't keep any files on your system (in contrast to a normal "remove", which might leave configuration files, etc.):

```
sudo apt-get purge mendeleydesktop
```

Comment: `purge` doesn't work either. I just tried, and after reinstalling, my library was still right there. Didn't even need to sign in. I even removed its directories from `~/.config`, `~/.local`, and `~/.cache`.