# Uninstall and purge mendeley and its config files

Tags: ubuntu, uninstall

I'm trying to debug an issue with [Mendeley](https://www.mendeley.com), but I can't figure out how to actually get rid of all its configuration after uninstalling it.

I've tried `sudo apt purge mendeleydesktop`, as suggested in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/278683/uninstall-mendeley/278688#278688), but when I reinstall it, my library is right there. I don't even need to sign back in!

I've tried removing the `Mendeley Ltd.` directory from `~/.config`, `~/.local/share`, and `~/.cache`, and even checked if any other Mendeley-related files exist with `find / -iname '*mendeley*'`.

As far as I can tell, I'm getting rid of every file Mendeley created. Yet when I reinstall it, it still comes back signed into my account! Does anyone have any idea how this is possible?

FYI, I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and installing from `mendeleydesktop_1.19.2-stable_amd64.deb`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have all data in the cloud, then you can do the following:

Open Mendeley desktop > Help > Reset Mendeley desktop.

You can now login and sync all Mendeley data.

Comment: Interesting. I'm past my original problem so I'm not brave enough to try it right now and nuke my current Mendeley, but I'll keep it in mind!

Answer (score 0):

I got similar question as I reinstalled mendeley that kept trying to connect to internet using the old configuration file that is there:

/home/loic/.config/Mendeley Ltd./Mendeley Desktop.conf

Browsing through this simple file, it seems to contain all the "options" we can set by mouse clicking in the GUI and there is also a login line.

My proposition is to look for this config file remove it and let mendeley make the new fresh one, I solve my issue this way and it should be helpful to many similar problems.

I found it thanks to your nice find command that found tons of other files, so if your find shows nothing I guess it is just because of an error in the location of search.

Loïc, Grenoble

PS: the backup of database seems really good and clear (does not contains pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Most of the data is located in '.local/share/data/Mendeley Ltd.' so that one is quite important to delete for a fresh reinstall.